# How can I change table layout to div layout?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to change the HTML structure from `table` to `div` using JavaScript, jQuery or any other way?

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" style="width: 500px; ">
<tbody>
    <tr><td><strong>CONNECTORS</strong></td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>USB:</td><td>AMC</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Gigabit Ethernet:</td><td>AMC</td></tr> 
    <tr><td>VGA:</td><td>AMC</td></tr>
    <tr><td>RS232:</td><td>AMC</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;   </td></tr>
    <tr><td><strong>PHYSICAL CHARACTERISTICS</strong></td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Dimensions:</td><td>220 x 88 x 280mm (WxHxD)</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Weight:</td><td>4,6kg</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Color:</td><td> Green, other optional</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;   </td></tr>
</tbody>
```

So after hack it should look like this:

```
<div style="width:500px">
    <div class="block"> 
        <div><strong>CONNECTORS</strong></div>
        <div class="lft">USB:</div><div class="rght">AMC</div>
        <div class="lft">Gigabit Eithernet</div><div class="rght">AMC</div>    
        <div class="lft">VGA:</div><div class="rght">AMC</div>   
        <div class="lft">RS232:</div><div class="rght">AMC</div>             
    </div>

    <div class="block"> 
        <div><strong>PHYSICAL CHARACTERS</strong></div>
        <div class="lft">Dimensions</div><div class="rght">220 x 88 x 280mm (WxHxD)</div>
        <div class="lft">weight:</div><div class="rght">AMC</div>    
        <div class="lft">Color:</div><div class="rght">AMC</div>   
        <div class="lft">power:</div><div class="rght">9-32VDC</div>             
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Don't do this using javascript. Amend the source.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Rory is correct, change the source

Comment: It's possible yes, but would be complicated and use so much processing that it might make your site slow. It would be a bit insane to do this with jQuery, much better to change the source or make do with the table layout and use clever CSS to achieve what you want.

Comment: There are a lot of tables in the database. It is not possible to change them one by one. It would take much time.

Comment: *Take the time*. Your UI will be horrifically slow and the maintenance of this hack will be a nightmare if you try and turn a table layout to divs using jQuery.

Comment: You are right. I should not change it into div. But is it possible to group a bunch of rows each time a row with <strong></strong> element appears. So I could apply a zebra stripping.

Comment: I edited my response for adding a SQL-oriented solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure is a good idea but you can do something like that.

If you have a wrapper around the table like:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td><strong>CONNECTORS</strong></td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td>USB:</td><td>AMC</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Gigabit Ethernet:</td><td>AMC</td></tr>
            ...
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Then:

```
var content = $('#wrapper').html().replace(/table/g, 'div').replace(/tbody/g, 'div').replace(/tr><td/g, 'div').replace(/td><\/tr/g, 'div');

$('#wrapper').html(content);
```

My example is just to give you the idea, you can achieve it with a single regex and a single replace().

Demo : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/btRuz/)

---

**Edit:** If the HTML is saved into a database, you can directly replace it into the database.

Example with SQL Server :

```sql
UPDATE myDatabase SET html = REPLACE(html, 'table', 'div') WHERE html LIKE '%table%';
UPDATE myDatabase SET html = REPLACE(html, 'tbody', 'div') WHERE html LIKE '%tbody%';
...
```

You have to be sure of your queries if that database is in production.

Comment: Your example works good. It is amazing. But it indent the two td's text close so it seems one text.

Comment: It was just the idea, you can modify the regexes to get the result you want.